# Better solution for this foreach? PHP GET POST

Tags: php, performance, foreach, smarty

I wrote this function to clean and convert incoming GET POST parameters.
Clean function contains:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $str = stripslashes($str);
}

$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
$search = array('"', "\"", "'", "\'", "\\", "", ")", "$", "}","{", "`", "´");
$str = str_replace($search, "",$str);
```

Problem is: while no GET POST parameres, it takes 1.0108 seconds on my Dualcore 1.6GHz notebook with 4 GB of ram.

```
//this to avoid undefined variables    
$variableList = array(
    "action" => "get",
    "site" => "get",
    "lng" => "get",
    "save_profile" => "post",
    "pass" => "post",
    "name" => "post",
    "logout" => "get",
    "page" => "get"
);

foreach ($variableList as $key => $value)
{
    ${"_" . $value . ucfirst(clean($key))} = false;
    $smarty->assign("_$value" . ucfirst(clean($key)), false);
}

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    ${"_get" . ucfirst(clean($key))} = clean($value);
    $smarty->assign("_get" . ucfirst(clean($key)), ${"_get" . ucfirst(clean($key))});
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    ${"_post" . ucfirst(clean($key))} = clean($value);
    $smarty->assign("_post" . ucfirst(clean($key)), ${"_post" . ucfirst(clean($key))});
}
```

So do you have any sugestion?

Comment: You do call `clean()` on every `$key` and `$value` twice.

Comment: i found why it is slow, removing mysql_real_escape_string makes it lighting fast ( 0.0015 seconds), but i want to use this function or something like this.

Comment: It needs a DB connection, perhaps that's why.

Comment: Why do you need to call that? You should stop using mysql functions, you should use prepared statements with mysqli or PDO.

Comment: If you really need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string`, call it once just before interpolating the variable into the query string, not in the loop.